# How to extract hashtag content?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract the content following a hashtag using php.

For example:

```
$sentence = 'This #Coffee is the #best!!';
```

How do I get the value '*Coffee*' and '*best*'? Note, I don't want the exclamation mark after '*best*'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A pretty safe catch-all in utf-8/unicode:

```
preg_match_all('/#([\p{L}\p{Mn}]+)/u',$string,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Although, if you're not using / expecting exotic characters, this might work equally well and is more readable:

```
preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/',$string,$matches);
```

Comment: I've modified the regex to include hashtags that can also contain underscores and numeric characters ie. #NYE2016: preg_match_all('/#([\p{Pc}\p{N}\p{L}\p{Mn}]+)/u', $string, $matches);

Comment: Might I recommend doing `preg_match_all('/[\s]+#([\p{Pc}\p{N}\p{L}\p{Mn}]+)/u', $content, $matches);` with the addition of the `[\s]+` to prevent anchors from being converted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
|\#(\w*)|
```

Run in a sentence like

I want to get all #something with #this

It will retrieve "something" and "this". Im assuming that you only wanted the Regex, the function to use is preg_match_all

Comment: I know is not a Regex entity, but is just a habit to escape things that Im not too sure. It works just fine both ways.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like better:

```
preg_match_all('/#([^#]+)#/msiU',$string,$matches);
```

to handle multiline sentences